# Calculating pi to 7 significant figures without using Math.PI

Tags: java, numerical-methods

I need to calculate pi to 7 significant figures in Java—*without* using Math.PI.

Here is the code I came up with to do that:

```
public class ComputePI 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        double sum = 0.0;
        double sumOne = 0.0;
        double delta;
        int counter = 0;
        final double DENOMINATOR_CANCEL = 4.0;
        final int LARGE_NUMBER = 5000000;
        final double SMALLEST_DELTA = 0.0000004535899;
        boolean closeEnough = false;      

        for (int j = 1; j < LARGE_NUMBER; j += 2) // Computes number close to pi
        {
            double firstFrac = (1.0 / (j * 2.0 - 1.0));
            double secondFrac = (1.0 / (j * 2.0 + 1.0));
            sumOne += firstFrac - secondFrac;
        }

        for (int i = 1; (!closeEnough); i += 2)   //"My computed value of pi" 
        {
            double firstNum = (1.0 / (i * 2.0 - 1.0));
            double secondNum = (1.0 / (i * 2.0 + 1.0));     
            sum += firstNum - secondNum;
            delta = sumOne * DENOMINATOR_CANCEL - sum * DENOMINATOR_CANCEL;
            if (delta < SMALLEST_DELTA)     // If delta reaches 7-sig accuracy
            {
                closeEnough = true;         // End loop
            }
            counter = i / 2;        // Counts iterations
        }

                        /*  output results      */
        System.out.println("My computed value of pi is: " + sum * DENOMINATOR_CANCEL);
        System.out.println("The library constant value of pi is: " + Math.PI);
        System.out.println("The number of iterations needed to reach " + "seven-significant digit accuracy is: " + counter);
    }       
}
```

Is this a good approach, or is it horribly inefficient? How might I improve it?

Perhaps having a `for` loop inside a `for` loop would work better. One with *n+1* iterations, the other with *n* iterations. The loop would terminate if the two sums were subtracted, and produced a difference of 0.0000009 or less (7 significant figure accuracy).

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is fine. You could add some tweaks (`i += 4` instead of `i += 2`) to avoid multiplying `i` by 2.0, but this won't help much to make your program fast.

This is because you chose a simple formula, but that formula converges very slowly towards \$\pi\$.

Read on Wikipedia about efficient algorithms for computing \$\pi\$, there are several.

Or, if you want to cheat a bit, just return `4 * Math.atan(1.0)`.

You don't need a `delta` in the whole program, so only declare it where you really need it. You already did that with `firstFrac`, for example.

Be consistent with your chosen names. What's the difference between `firstFrac` and `firstNum`? — There is none, therefore you should use the same name in both places.

What does `sumOne` mean? Think of a better name for it.